# Unable to use GPU to Fit Model using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a windows 10 Operating system and I am using Tensorflow gpu version on Jupyter Notebook.

conda 4.9.2

python 3.7

tf '2.3.1'

cudatoolkit 11.0.221

```
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
```

returns:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
```

and,

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

returns:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 10428669251348137268
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 2248949917928228630
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 17815507612308274706
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

However, when I want to fit model, it starts using 100 percent of my CPU instead of GPU.

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: you need cudatoolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way to get there is uninstall tensorflow. The if you have anaconda installed
install tensflow using conda. It will install tensorflow 2.1.1, cudatoolkit 10.1.243 and cudnn 7.65. These are compatible with tensorflow 2.31. Then use pip to install tensorflow 2.3.1. Conda for windows can only install tensorflow up to version2.1.